# Fluentd is always creates directory rather than log file

Tags: logging, fluentd

I'm new to fluentd. My problem is that instead of creating a log file, this configuration always creates a folder:

```
<source>
  @type http
  port 7090
  tag moodle.hub
</source>

<match moodle.hub>
  @type file
  path /var/log/moodle/myapp.log
  compress gzip
  <buffer>
    timekey 10s
    timekey_use_utc true
    timekey_wait 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

How can I change it? It must create a log file `myapp.log`.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the name of that folder? Is it empty?

Comment: the name of the folder is myapp.log, instead of making it a log file its always creates a myapp.log folder. and its an empty folder.

Comment: Even after 10 seconds, there's no file? Take a look at [append](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file#append) also.

Comment: yes even after an hour theres still no file created.

Comment: I tried append but still the same no progress.

Comment: How are sending events to `http` input plugin?

Comment: I've just tested your config included with `append true` using `curl -X POST -d 'json={"foo":"bar"}' http://localhost:7090/moodle.hub`. It works. The files are being created. Sample Files: `myapp.log.20201013111840.log.gz`, `myapp.log.20201013111850.log.gz`, etc.

Comment: its not working to me, Im using windows, and installed fluentd using .msi

Comment: How are you sending events to fluentd? From some command-line tool or some application?

Comment: I'm using a browser, I need to log my local site. this is the url http://localhost:7090/work/rehub/moodle/my/

Comment: Right. Are you using any HTTP requests to pass logs to fluentd's http input plugin?

Comment: no i don't use any http request, I thought it will be automatically log if I only set an @type http in fluentd with a port, actually i don't really know this fluentd someone suggested this logger to me thats why I'm using this.  I find fluentd really hard to configure haha,

Comment: the server that Im using is laragon, Im using moodle framework an lms, and I want to log errors like http status errors using fluentd. Im running fluentd using this command in td-agent comand prompt >fluentd -c etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf. I tried many configuration, but still, it always create a directory instead of a log file.

Comment: even this kind of path didn't work path /var/log/hub/access/access.%Y-%m-%d.%H%M.log, it only creates a folder the folder it creates is access.%Y-%m-%d.%H%M.log instead of date.

Comment: Well, the input to fluentd is through source section. You are not providing any input that's why you're not seeing anything. The match section is to configure output plugins. I'd suggest to go through its documentation first. Configure it with different plugins and get an idea how it actually works.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-php and https://docs.fluentd.org/language-bindings/php